# Trying to create a loop method to add WordPress meta boxes based on files with form fields in folder

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I wrote a method to scan a directory for XML files and **dynamically create WordPress metaboxes** for page and post types. All works fine **except** when looping to load the file within the `add_meta_box()` callback function enclosure.

### The desired output

Should return only the fields associated with each meta box.

[image: desired output of fields]

#### The actual output

Each box returns the same fields from all files found.

[image: erroneous output]

#### The coding

```
public static function getForms($dir)
{
    global $metaboxes, $configforms;
    $metaboxes = mb::filelist($dir, '^metabox_', true); // returns an array of full path files
    
    if( !empty($metaboxes) ) 
    {
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() 
        {
            global $metaboxes, $metabox_path;
            $metabox_path=[];
            foreach($metaboxes as $metabox) 
            {
                $form = simplexml_load_file($metabox);
                $boxval = $form->attributes();
                
                $boxid = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', (string)$boxval->boxlabel)).'-metaboxid';
                $posttypes = (isset($boxval->posttype) ? explode(',', (string)$boxval->posttype) : get_post_types());
                $col = (isset($boxval->col) ? (string)$boxval->col : 'normal');
                $priority = (isset($boxval->priority) ? (string)$boxval->priority : '');
                $metabox_path[] = substr($metabox,0,-4);
                
                // create each metabox
                foreach($posttypes as $posttype) 
                {
                    add_meta_box($boxid, (string)$boxval->boxlabel, function() 
                    {
                        global $metabox_path;

                        foreach($metabox_path as $path) 
                        {
                            // pass the XML file to the form field processor
                            // the method will echo the output
                            self::form($path);
                        }
                        
                    }, strtolower($posttype), $col, $priority);
                }
                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### The XML file content

**metabox_photos.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form boxlabel="Photo Boxes">
    <fields>
        <fieldset>
            <field type="text" name="sosphoto" label="The List" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

Other XML
**metabox_woofield.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form posttype="post,page" col="normal" priority="high" boxlabel="Woo Fields">
    <fields>
        <fieldset>
            <field type="text" name="woobox" label="Wooten" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

I've tried conditions within the `add_meta_box()` function closure to match current metabox ID using the global var `$wp_meta_boxes` and compare to the `$boxid` variable, and the erroneous result persisted.

**How can I get this method to deliver the desired result?**

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution defined!

I removed the `global` variables and implemented the PHP keyword `use`, then wrapped the `add_meta_box()` function withing the `foreach()` loop and passed the `$path` variable to the closure.

```
public static function getForms($dir)
{
    $metaboxes = mb::filelist($dir, '^metabox_', true);
    
    if( !empty($metaboxes) ) 
    {
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() use ($metaboxes)
        {
            $metabox_path=[];
            foreach($metaboxes as $metabox) 
            {
                $form = simplexml_load_file($metabox);
                $boxval = $form->attributes();
                
                $boxid = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', (string)$boxval->boxlabel)).'-metaboxid';
                $posttypes = (isset($boxval->posttype) ? explode(',', (string)$boxval->posttype) : get_post_types());
                $col = (isset($boxval->col) ? (string)$boxval->col : 'normal');
                $priority = (isset($boxval->priority) ? (string)$boxval->priority : '');
                $metabox_path[] = substr($metabox,0,-4);
                
                
                foreach($posttypes as $posttype) 
                {
                    foreach($metabox_path as $path) 
                    {
                        add_meta_box($boxid, (string)$boxval->boxlabel, function() use ($path) {
                            self::form($path);
                            
                        }, strtolower($posttype), $col, $priority);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        });
```

### The result

[image: correct output]

### The XML files loaded per meta box

**metabox_photos.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form boxlabel="Photo Boxes">
    <fields>
        <fieldset>
            <field type="text" name="sosphoto" label="The List" />
            <field type="textarea" name="flood" label="World" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

**metabox_woofield.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form posttype="post,page" col="normal" priority="high" boxlabel="Woo Fields">
    <fields>
        <fieldset>
            <field type="text" name="woobox" label="Wooten" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```